# Grails 2.5.4 Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: java, spring-mvc, grails, grails-2.5, spring-loaded

I'm trying to run an application in Grails but I have a problem with the execution. I'm using grails version 2.5.4 and Java version 1.7.
I checked my enviroment variables and they turned out to be OK.

This is the error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM agent library failed to init: instrument.
>
> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Program%20Files\Grails\grails-2.5.4\lib\org.springframework\springloaded\jars\springloaded-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar
>
> Error | Forked Grails VM exited with error

What's going on?

Comment: the error basically tell that the file at specified path is missing or corrupted. Have you tried checking that path? Is the file there?

Comment: Try reinstalling Grails in a directory that doesn't have spaces in it.